# Easy and appropriate setup of a python script

Tags: python

What's the appropriate way to setup a python environment automatically without using pip/setuptools?

I'm required to do this for a project and I'm not allowed to 'install' anything on the server. I don't have permissions for that and it's a script that will be used by multiple users.

I need to set up the PYTHONPATH so modules can be imported in the package as well as create symbolic links for my command line script. It's my first time doing this so I'll appreciate your help a lot.

My project folder looks something like:

```
ProjectName/
  README
  LICENSE
  projectname/
    projectname # command-line script
    src/
      module1.py
      module2.py
    tests/
      test.py
```

Should I just create a quick bash script to do this or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you have access to the server's .bashrc? You can append to the PYTHONPATH there.

Comment: Are you actually looking for something like `py2exe`?

Comment: Yeah since you do not have permissions, did you check whether you have to access to the server's bashrc file.

Comment: @J.Blackadar Only to mine. I would like to automate that somehow so every new user doesnt have to do all that manually.

Comment: @cap You could add default configurations in /etc/skel/.bashrc so that useradd(8) can copy files in /etc/skel whenever it creates new user's directory by '-m' option. This will only affect new users. Otherwise packaging with a freeze tool might be a better option.